# Socket Programming read and write hang

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm trying to do a simple server client program using sockets in C (local sockets). I've managed to get my client to successfully write to the server. The server then takes the char runs a few functions to write a new char to the client. The issue is after the first write and read, the client hangs waiting for the server. Snippet of server:

```
listen (serverCT, 5);

    while (1)
    {
        /*Accept a client connection*/
        clientCT = accept (serverCT, clientSockAddrPtr, &clientLen);

        if (fork () == 0)
        {
    printf ("Session Started");
    readCountry (clientCT);
    //printf ("main %s\n", rCountry);
    writeCapital (clientCT);
            close (clientCT);
            exit (0);
        }
        else
            close (clientCT);

    }
```

Snippet of client:

```
do
{
    result = connect (clientCT, serverSockAddrPtr, serverLen);
    if (result == -1) sleep (1);
}
while (result == -1);
//Send Country to Server//
writeCountry (clientCT);
sleep (1);
readCapital (clientCT);
//readCurrency (clientCT);
close (clientCT);
exit(0);
```

Read country and write country work fine. But when server tries to run write capital(server) it hangs, and can only continue after i kill the client process. What am i missing here?

edit##
writeCapital function:

```
writeCapital (int fd)
{
  char* capitalName = getCapital(rCountry);
    printf ("%s\n", capitalName);
write (fd, capitalName, strlen(capitalName) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Well, you didn't really include writeCapital definition

Comment: writeCapital function has been defined in fact it only runs when i kill the client.

Comment: You miss my point, your error lies in writeCapital but you didn't include it here in your code listing so we can't help you

Comment: It indicates you are not correctly terminates string when send it from client, or do not detect termination char on server. It could be '\n' char, for example

Comment: @Puciek edited my question to include writeCapital.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk how does a termination char help? The client has successfully sent the information to the server now the server is unable to carry on with the next step.

Comment: The server has no information when the client ends to send data. Unless the protocol is datagram (not in this case), or you follow some convention (fixed length, termination char, other contract). You use `0` as termination char in `writeCapital`. So it is likely you are blocking on read without checking for it.

Comment: Your source code is incomplete and lacks almost all error checking.

Comment: @EJP i agree my source code is incomplete and lacks error checking. In fact i did find my error after staring at my code for close to 2 hours.If i may ask what are the methods of error checking that can be used for a program in C.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk thanks for your help, you pointed me in the right direction. There was another related function that had a loop that was not terminating i changed it and got the results that i desired. Much thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @seelani: Test the results of (system) calls against the value indicating a failure as per the (system) calls documentation.